# How to fetch numbers from eventlog message using powershell regex?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using powershell to get an event log message for the below example:

> Disk 3 has crossed a capacity utilization threshold and used
>   19683350528 bytes. When the threshold was crossed, the disk had
>   87690831360 bytes of remaining capacity.

I need to get the Disknumber 3, Threshold Bytes 19683350528 and Remaining Bytes 87690831360.

I know `select-string -pattern` can be used. But don't know the regular expression to fetch those values.

```
Function Get-LogSensemessage
{  
   Param
   (
   $LogMessage
   )

   $DiskNumber=  $LogMessage | select-string -pattern <Regular expression>
   $Threshold = $LogMessage | select-string -pattern <Regular expression>
   $RemainingCapacity =  $LogMessage | select-string -pattern <Regular expression>

[pscustomobject]@{ 
  DiskNumber = $disknumber
  Threshold = $Threshold
  RemainingCapacity = $RemainingCapacity

}

}
```

Can someone help me to get the details with a regular expression?

Comment: Why not use `\d+` https://regex101.com/r/2yayo9/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, you can use the regex pattern `\d+` to match anything that is a number in the string. We can get all the matches in one hit by using the `-AllMatches` switch on `Select-String`.

Here's how I suggest you incorporate it in your function:

```
Function Get-LogSensemessage
{  
    Param(
       [string]$LogMessage
    )

    $LogValues = ($LogMessage | Select-String -Pattern '\d+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value

    [pscustomobject]@{ 
        DiskNumber = $LogValues[0]
        Threshold = $LogValues[1]
        RemainingCapacity = $LogValues[2]
    }
}
```

`$LogValues` becomes an array of strings, so we get each matched value by using the array index starting from `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `[0-9]+` pattern

Answer (score 1):

Use `-AllMatches` parameter, run the `Select-String` only once and assign values from the results:

```
$results = $text | Select-String -Pattern "\d+" -AllMatches
$FirstNum = $results.Matches[0].value
$SecondNum = $results.Matches[1].value
```